# Best Way to Save Chat History in Messenger app

Tags: android, chat, asmack

hope you be doing fine.here i need a little experience assist for compeleting my asmack based chat application, i need to know which is best way to keep chatmessages history, and retain them to ui upon request,i have done that with database but i am not saticified with it at all, it lowers the page opening speed by a big deal,i also could do that with SharedPreferences,but i dont have any experience with that in case of such thing.

I really appreciate if you could please give me a tip about what way all chat app's use to save and retain chat history or which way is best to do so?

thanks alot.

this is how i create or open the database:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("singlechat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

this is how i insert into database ( i create a new table for every new user )

```
final String Text = event.text;
    final String Type = "m";    
    final String name = event.name;
    final Blob OtherFormats = null;
    final String Date = event.itime;
    final Blob Image = null;
    final String RealName = "s";
    final String ID = "" ;

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + name
        + "  (ID           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + "   Type            TEXT,"
        + "   Text         TEXT,"
        + "   OtherFormats           BLOB,"
        + "   Date           TEXT,"
        + "   Image     BLOB,"
        + "   RealName TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sqlCreate);


String sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO " + "'"+name+"'"+"   
   (Type,Text,OtherFormats,Date,Image,RealName)VALUES
 ("+"'"+Type+"'"+","+"'"+Text+"'"+","+"'"+       
 OtherFormats+"'"+","+"'"+Date+"'"+","+"'"+Image+"'"+","+"'"+RealName+"')"; 


db.execSQL(sqlInsert);
          }

    });
t.start();

}
```

and here is a simple array adapter:

```
  public static ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  private static ListView listview;

 public void setListAdapter() {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
 R.layout.listitem, messages);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: Are you using a ListView in transcript mode? Show us the Java code for your ListView. There is probably something you're missing in it.

Comment: yes im using a simple adapter and add data 1by1 to that, gimme a sec

Comment: Im afraid im not familiar with tanscript you mentioned, but i have a sweeping tab on main view, insidie on of these  there are chats,also if doesnt bother you i need to know how can i save the loaded data so when i go back to main activity, i shall not reload the data.is the Loader my solution?